# Datepicker missing with English locale. What is may be wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datapicker

I have datepicker, on jsp page here:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['<%=response.getLocale().getLanguage()%>']);

$("#dateinputOne, #dateinputTwo").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    beforeShowDay: beforeShowDayHandler,
    showOn: 'both',
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", false);
    },
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

I use three languages: Russian, English, Chinese to change locale. Everything works fine until I change to english. Russian and Chinese works fine, but when I change on English, instead English I see Chinese. **What may be a problem with it???**

I check this code: `'<%=response.getLocale().getLanguage()%>'` and it returns `en` like and `ru` or `cn` for Chinese. Getting to hear from you folks. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use empty string "" instead of "en" as index of $.datepicker.regional.

It should look like this:

```
$.datepicker.regional['<%=response.getLocale().getLanguage() == "en" ? "" : response.getLocale().getLanguage()%>']
```

Comment: but what about other languages?? I want them also be available for datepicker??

Comment: Leave other languages as is. Use empty string only in case of "en" locale.

Comment: I don't know your server language but it should look like this: `$.datepicker.regional['<%=response.getLocale().getLanguage() == "en" ? "" : response.getLocale().getLanguage()%>']`

Comment: Yes I know that empty string only in case of "en" locale, but how to do so?? Leave other languages as it is??